multi monitor setup - window positions in full-screen
So I have two monitors and I would like some windows to be on the second monitor. Problem is that whenever I start a full-screen game, it totally changes it and puts some different windows on that second monitor! Why does it do it and what can I do about it? Funnily I can move the mouse over there and use mouse wheel to scroll in it, but once I click there it switches away from that full-screen app and I get back to the setup as before. I have no idea how to influence what appears on the second screen while the first screen is in fullscreen mode.
EDIT: I noticed that if the game in fullscreen has the same resolution as desktop then it seems windows don't get reorganized and what I put on the second screen stays there! So as a workaround I have lowered my primary screen resolution in desktop from 4K to QHD to match the fullscreen game and it's fine now

From my experience there are a lot of factors to consider. Monitor, graphics card, and the game itself.
In most cases, you should be able to go into the graphics settings in the game, and under full-screen, change it to either "Windowed full-screen" or in a worst-case scenario, just "windowed".
Sometimes the full-screen interactions with games within windows can be quite aggressive, especially older games that both force full-screen and specific resolutions.
If you're using Steam to launch your games, there is a program on steam called Borderless Gaming that allows you to launch games in proper full-screen while rendering it in a windowed container. Neat little trick but a little finicky, however.

Other things that affect it can be: Which monitor is set as primary, the connections to the graphics card (which port each monitor is plugged into), type of connection DVI/DisplayPort/HDMI and which monitor is on the left or right of the other one.

it's Minecraft and yes it can be played windowed, but I don't like the border you know.
